# Alpine and Alpine-Linux tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags

People inadvertently choose the tag [alpine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine) (an email client) instead of [alpine-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux). See the recent question  [How to create Alpine live-USB without using `dd`?](https://superuser.com/q/1287166/).

I suggest to remove the tag alpine and replace it with alpine-mail or another variation. There is a relevant discussion in https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4747/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I cleaned up the tag assignments, so all [alpine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine) questions are now about the email client and all [alpine-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux) questions have only that tag.  I added clarification to the [alpine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine) wiki excerpt (pending review), but concur that the [alpine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine) tag should be renamed [alpine-mail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine-mail), consistent with how it was handled on the Unix & Linux site.

Answer (score 7):

As the tags have effectively been cleaned up and split by fixer1234 I have gone ahead and merged [alpine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine) into [alpine-mail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alpine-mail)

```
Merge Results

updating post history, 29 rows affected (pipe delimited) 
updating posts, 26 rows affected (pipe delimited) 
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected tag 
remapping of [alpine-mail] and [alpine] complete! 
remapping 0 synonyms 
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped! 
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Creating a synonym didn't seem relevant here, neither mail nor Linux are popular enough to be considered "primary".